# Cross Referencing Notes in R Markdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, bookdown

I'm using R Markdown for latex output. I have a single document with body text and a supplementary section with figures, tables, and notes that I want referenced as Figure S1, Table S1, and Note S2 for instance without manually having to number them; whereas the main text figures and tables are to be referenced without the S.

The notes also have citations in standard Rmd form `[@citationkey]`. In the current scenario I can get the figures to work but not the notes, especially not with the citation keys.

In the code below I've hard coded the headings (Note S1, Note S2) but if the numbering can be automated, that would be even better.

````
---
title: "Title"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: false
    extra_dependencies: ["float"]
    template: NULL
    keep_tex: true
    number_sections: false
    latex_engine: pdflatex
  word_document: default
always_allow_html: yes
documentclass: article
bibliography: references2.bib
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{amsthm}
  - \usepackage[subrefformat=simple]{subfig}
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage{longtable}
  - \usepackage{array}
  - \usepackage{multirow}
  - \usepackage{wrapfig}
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \usepackage{pdflscape}
  - \usepackage{tabu}
  - \usepackage{threeparttable}
  - \usepackage{threeparttablex}
  - \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
  - \usepackage{makecell}
  - \usepackage{xcolor}  
  - \usepackage{svg}
  - \usepackage{biblatex}
  - \newcommand{\beginsupplement}{
    \setcounter{table}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}     
    \setcounter{figure}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
    \newcounter{note}
    \setcounter{note}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thenote}{S\arabic{note}}}
includes:
  in_header: ["preamble.tex", 'gt_packages.sty']
---

# Main Text
The main text. See Figure \@ref(fig:fig-plot) for a plot as well as \@ref(note:note-dg). 

## Supplementary Information
\beginsupplement 

## Supplemental Figures

```{r fig-plot, warnings= FALSE}
#| fig.cap: "Plot"
#| echo: false
#| out.width: "40%"
#| fig.align: "center"

plot(pressure)
```

## Supplemental Tables

```{r ST-bgintervals, echo = FALSE}
summary(pressure)
```


## Supplemental Notes
### Note S1: Data Gathering
Some text goes here. 
\label{note:note-dg}
Data was obtained from [@citationkey1; @citationkey2]. 

### Note S2: Plot
Plot was made using base R [@citationkey3]
````